# Is there a tree data type in windows libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, tree

Working in C#. I need a simple tree data type to store some objects.

Is there a native windows libraries tree data type?

I've looked in System.Collections.Generic but couldn't find anything.

Tried Googling it, all I see is custom built trees.

Comment: No, there is no tree structure in BCL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, There isn't a tree data type in `.Net` for two reasons:

1. Trees are almost always built specifically for a certain usage and there isn't a general case for them like, for example, a dictionary.
2. It's really simple to build a basic tree. You just write a `TreeNode` class that references 2 or more `TreeNode` children. Maybe add a Tree class to hold them. That's all.